# What is core government debt?

Tags: government-debt, bonds, usa

> In fixed income, the yield on the 10-year US Treasury fell 0.07
>   percentage points to 0.56 per cent as investors retreated to the
>   safety of core government debt

From : https://www.ft.com/content/26ea5ef9-0619-4e50-b605-58e36d3fc4d9

What is 'core government debt' and how is it raised, since the quoted statement seems to imply it is different from US Treasury bonds.

Answer (score 1):

There’s no formal meaning, but it would be the perceived safest government bonds. The quote indicates thar US Treasury bonds are part of that core. The 10-year yield fell, which meant that price went up.